# Python 3 - Print numbers from a list whose square value is evenly divisible by 8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a question to determine if a square value in a list is evenly divisible by 8, and then print it out from the list if this is the case. So for example I can have this list:

```
 list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

- 4 squared = 16, which is divisible evenly by 8.
- 8 square = 64, which is divisible by 8, etc.

So, the program has to print the square values that are divisible by 8. I have realised, I have to use the `print()` function as well as "for" and "in" most likely since its a loop type question.

As a reference, here is the original question:

Print each number in a list whose 
square
 is evenly divisible by 8.

**For example, if list is**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

, then the number 4 is one number that should be printed because 4 squared 
is 16 and 16 is evenly divisible by 8. Test your code module with 
**two**
 test lists.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if the square of `x` is divisible by 8, then `x` is divisible by `4`, so:

```
list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
print [x for x in list1 if x & 3 == 0]
```

Comment: Awesome answer but can you please explain about `x & 3` and how it works here

Comment: @The6thSense, `&` is bitwise `and` (like in many other programming languages). You could instead use modulus: `[x for x in list1 if x % 4 == 0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
num_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

First you iterate over the list. Use the `for` loop for it. Put your if condition in there `if (x * x) % 8 == 0 then print the number`:

```
for num in num_list:
    if (num * num) % 8 == 0:
        print(num)
```

The key idea is finding the square, for it you use `num * num`.

To check if a number `x` is divisible by 8 you use `x % 8 == 0`